# put a picture on a label python tkinter

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I have found a similar question here, but the answer did not help.

I have a python skript and a .gif

Both are in the same directory.
I am trying the following:

```
 master = Tk()       
 left = PhotoImage(file = "A.gif")
```

However, I get an "No such file or directory" Exception for the gif.

Where do I put it to avoid this

Answer (score 2):

You mention that the `.gif` and the `.py` are in the same directory, but that's not actually relevant.

What is relevant is whether the `.gif` is in the *current working directory* of your python process.

Try one of these:

1. setting your shell's current working directory to the directory that holds the `.gif`, or
2. using an absolute path name in the `PhotoImage` call